# Extracting values out of a python list as individual entities

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, web2py

please someone out there coz I'm pulling out my hairs at this point:
I want to extract pictures from within a list extracted from the database and store them inside a JavaScript array for a slide show. I am using a web2py framework.
**CONTROLLER**

```
>`def form1Details():
  form=db.compForm(request.args(0))
  forms=db(db.compFormPages.formName==form.id).\
  select(db.compFormPages.ALL)
  return locals()
```

`

the images are in variable forms so i wanna display them in my view such that each picture is stored individually inside a JavaScript array for a slide show like below

**VIEW**

```
>`{{for pic in forms:}}
 <script>
function slideShow()
{
images = ["{{=URL('download',args=pic.formImage)}}",
"{{=URL('download',args=pic2.formImage)}}"],
"{{=URL('download',args=pic3.formImage)}}"];
descriptions=['{{=pic.formTitle}}',
'{{=pic2.formTitle}}',
'{{=pic2.formTitle}}';
...............
...............
</script>
}`
```

How do I extract them individually to achieve whats in the view above, i could use all the help i could get, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your goal is some Javascript code with a variable holding an array of URLs and another variable holding an array of descriptions, one simple approach is to use the `ASSIGNJS` helper, which will write the Javascript variables and generate their values by converting the associated Python data structures to JSON. So, in the view:

```
<script>
function slideShow() {
  {{=ASSIGNJS(images=[URL('default', 'download', args=form.formImage)
                      for form in forms],
              descriptions=[form.formTitle for form in forms])}}
  ...
}
</script>
```

That will yield Javascript like this:

```
var images = ["/myapp/default/download/image1", "/myapp/default/download/image2", ...];
var descriptions = ["Title 1", "Title 2", ...]
```

You might also instead consider generating an array of Javascript objects containing both the URL and description for each image:

```
{{=ASSIGNJS(images=[dict(url=URL('default', 'download', args=form.formImage),
                         description=form.formTitle)
                    for form in forms])}}
```

which will yield:

```
var images = [{"url": "/myapp/default/download/image1", "description": "Title 1"}, ...];
```

Comment: How can i display all these images without having to specify their count because the slide show sometimes shows 5 images and at times shows 3 images depending on what link the user clicked and all these images are taken from different tables in the database so the number of images is never standard, how to i cater for a different number of images displayed under varying user preferences determined by the links they click???

Comment: Your question asked how to get the list of image URLs into a Javascript array, which the above code does. If you now need to know what to do with the Javascript array, you should probably update your question or ask a new one. Basically, though, you'll need some way to iterate through the array to generate the slide show. It is not clear how to answer, though, as you don't present any details about how you are creating the slide show via Javascript.

Comment: I'll present the details